# How to do shift in ranked numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have an array of ranks (obtained from `scipy.stats.rankdata`):

```
1 2 5 3 4
```

The no.s are the ranks assigned to the corresponding indices. Now I want to shift the ranks downward by 2 positions. That is, I want the indices with the top 2 ranks to be assigned the last 2 ranks. The other elements must therefore increase in rank.

```
3 4 2 5 1
```

So the indices with the top 2 ranks i.e `index 2 and 4 having ranks 5 and 4` are given the bottom 2 ranks `2 and 1` . The other elements are increased in rank subsequently.

How do I implement this shift for any top `n` ranks?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
In [19]: ranks = np.array([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])

In [20]: n = 2

In [21]: new_ranks = (ranks + n - 1) % len(ranks) + 1

In [22]: new_ranks
Out[22]: array([3, 4, 2, 5, 1])
```

By adding `n` to the ranks and taking the result modulo `len(ranks)`, the high numbers wrap around to the low end.  The `-1` before modding shifts the values down by 1, because the modulo will work with the values `0, 1, 2, ... len(ranks) - 1`.  The +1 after modding restores the ranks to the range `1, 2, ..., len(ranks)`.